# can't get the custom grid filter working

Tags: extjs, filter, grid

What i want to do is a filter option in a column of a grid. THis is the column:

```
{
        id: 'kleuren',
        text: 'Kleuren',
        sortable: true,
        filterable: true,
        minWidth: 60,
        flexible: 0,
        width: 60,
        filter: {
            type: 'list',
            store: kleuren
        },
        renderer: kleurenWeergave,
        dataIndex: 'kleuren'
    }
```

for the store/model i use this

```
kleurenStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['id', 'text'],
    data: kleurenModel
});

 var kleurenModel = [
            ['rood', 'rood'],
            ['groen', 'groen'],
            ['blauw', 'blauw'],
            ['geel', 'geel']
            ]
```

This is my grid now

```
    var grid = Ext.create('PersistantSelectionGridPanel', {
    autoscroll: true,
    region: 'center',
    store: allLoaded,
    multiSelect: false,
    stateful: true,
    features: [filtersFeature],
    loadMask: false,
    stateId: 'stateGrid',
    viewConfig: {
        stripeRows: true
    },
    columns: [{....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of ExtJS are you running ? Cant debug much with the code you posted.

Can you post the code of your Grid ??

Your Grid should have a filters feature added as a config :

```
var filtersFeature = 
{
  ftype : 'filters',
  local : false,  // For Server Side Filtering
  encode : true
};
```

And your grid should have a config option

```
....
columns: defaultModel, 
loadMask: true,
features: [filtersFeature]  // To enable Filters
....
```

Comment: hey, i am using 4.1 If i do this i get an error:Error: Ext.Loader is not enabled, so dependencies cannot be resolved dynamically. Missing required class: feature.filters

Comment: you need to add 
   " requires: ['Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature'] "  
And you have to enable Ext Loader to enable dynamic dependencies.. This can be achieved by adding 
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});  in your Ext.onReady.. Something Like :-                         

Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});
});


Check this post for details :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715626/ext-loader-not-enabled-missing-required